# How I can delete grails domain object with many-to-many relationship?

Tags: grails, many-to-many, relationship

```
class Client {

String name
String surname
String address
static hasMany = [departments:Department]

}

class Department {

/*static constraints = {
}*/
String depName
String location
static hasMany = [clients:Client]
static belongsTo = Client
}

def deleteDepartment(){
    def values = params.list('departments')
    def checkedID = new Integer[values.size()]
    for(int i=0; i<values.size(); i++){
        String temp = values.get(i).toString()
        checkedID[i] = temp.toInteger()
    }

    for(int i=0; i<checkedID.length; i++){
        def department = Department.get(checkedID[i])
        department.clients.clear() //something
        department.save() //wrong
    }
}
```

Client has many departments. How I can delete Department domain object which has relationship with Client domain class, without deleting Client domain object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a common problem. When you create a many to many relationship

Your case will create three `tables` `client`, 'department`and`client_department`.

Now when you try to delete the department. Hibernate tries to remove the department from department table.

This will fails because its entry is already saved in `client_department` table with a foreign key reference.

This should ideally first remove the mapping entry and then remove the department from tables. but this is not how it works.

So a good workaround for maintaining many to many relationships is to keep this mapping in your own hands as shown below.

```
Client{}
Department{}
ClinetDepartment{
  Client client;
  Department department;
}
```

This will however force you to save the objects also independently.

like

```
client.save();
department.save();
new ClinetDepartment(client,department).save();
```

while deleting you can do

```
clinetDepartment.delete();
department.delete();
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
Department.get(id).delete()
```

You dont need to clear the clients because in your r/ship you dont have `Client` belongs to `Department` r/ship.

```
 department.clients.clear() //something
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution

```
def department = Department.get(checkedID[i])
        def tmp = []
        department.clients.each {tmp << it}
        tmp.each {department.removeFromClients(it)}
        department.delete(flush:true)
```